# Is there an inverse mode for Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-2007, word-2007

I'm wondering if there's any way to invert the colors in Microsoft Office Word - that is, view white text on a black background. I mainly ask because I'm used to dark color schemes a la Notepad++ themes and similar, and so much white space is really hard on the eyes in my environment.

I love Word, but want a sane color scheme - any options?
The product version is Office 2007 if that helps.

Some weird kludge or hack would also be acceptable :)

Comment: Perhaps change the system-wide accessibility theme? I seem to remember seeing 'reverse high-contrast' options before.

Comment: There certainly *used* to be a way to display white text on a blue background, a la WordPerfect. But it appears to be removed in the latest version. Last one I remember seeing it in is Office 2003. EDIT: Yeah, it's been unceremoniously removed from Word 2007. Check [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_office_word/archive/2009/03/02/word-throwback-just-write-edition1.aspx) for a possible workaround.

Comment: High contrast mode can be used easily.  Left-shift + left-Alt + PrtScr to turn it on and off.  Also available in "change desktop" and "ease of use" features.

Comment: In Word 2016 you can view a file in reading mode in which you can invert the colours.

Comment: Check this: https://www.davidbosman.fr/scsaw/?p=687 . You can choose View -> Immersive Reader. Then select Page Color -> Black.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Word is designed to show the document you're working on in as close to WYSIWYG mode as it can manage, which means white background and black (or coloured) text.
Haven't found a way to set a different background colour, but any text colour you set will result in that colour being printed which is probably not what you're looking for as a result.

Comment: Right, I'm looking for the text to display differently.

Comment: In Word 2019 you can go to `Design` > `Page Color` and choose a dark color.  It will automatically make the text lighter. It will also print dark on light.

Comment: Go to View=>Dark Mode => Switch Modes

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich now, yes. 10 years ago, no :)